# Razor Pages using EF Core Code First - Updated related entity using partial view

Tags: c#, razor, entity-framework-core

I'd like to preface this with, i'm pretty new to Razor pages, and EF, in fact this is my first major project using both, i've done all the tutorials on Microsoft Docs, and read around as much as I can, so I shall begin...

I've searched high and low for a proper solution on how to do this, and can't seem to find what i'm looking for (probably because i've been searching for the wrong thing?!!). I've got the following entities:

```
    public class Country
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }

    [Index(nameof(NameOrNumber), nameof(PostCode), IsUnique = true)]
    public class Address
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string NameOrNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Site
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int? AddressID { get; set; }
        public string MainPhone { get; set; }
        public bool isDeleted { get; set; }

        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
    }
```

There is also a building entity, which has an Address (linked to address entity, which might or might not be the same address (and ID) as the site's.  There are also other entities that use Address and may share addresses.  Hence why address is a separate entity and not just part of the Site (I didn't show Building as it's not directly relevant).

Essentially, i've created a partial view of the Address which i'm using as part of my create/update for an address, so when a site is created, the address is entered a fresh, but when I come to a Building, it may be that the address is the same, hence it'll have a choice of either.

This is the partial for the address (`_Address.cshtml`):

```
@model MyProject.Models.Address
@{
    SelectList CountryNames = (SelectList)ViewData["CountryNamesSL"];
}

<hr />
<div class="form-group">
    <h4>Address</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="NameOrNumber" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="NameOrNumber" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="NameOrNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Street" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Street" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Street" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="AddressLine2" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="AddressLine2" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="AddressLine2" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="AddressLine3" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="AddressLine3" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="AddressLine3" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="City" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="County" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="County" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="County" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PostCode" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="PostCode" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="PostCode" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Country" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="ID" class="form-control" asp-items="@CountryNames" name="CountryID"></select>
        @*<partial name="_Country" model="@Model.Country" />*@
        <span asp-validation-for="Country" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
```

So within my `Create.cshtml` for the `Site`, i've referenced the partial view, like so:

```
\\Other form elements removed for brevity

<partial name="_Address" model="@Model.Site.Address" />

\\rest of form + submit button
```

and the code code for creating the site with the related Address (`Create.cshtml.cs`):

```
    public class CreateModel : SelectListsPageModel //NOTE: The parent class provides methods for populating the country and region dropdowns
    {
        private readonly MyProject.Data.MyProjectContext _context;

        public CreateModel(MyProject.Data.MyProjectContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            PopulateRegionsDropDownList(_context);
            PopulateCountriesDropDownList(_context);

            Site = new Site();
            Site.Address = new Address();
            Site.Address.Country = new Country();

            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Site Site { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public Address Address { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int countryID)
        {
            var newSite = new Site();
            newSite.Address = Address;
            var Country = await _context.Countries.FindAsync(countryID);
            newSite.Address.Country = Country;

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Site>(
                newSite,
                "Site",
                s => s.RegionID,
                s => s.Name,
                s => s.Address,
                s => s.MainPhone)
            )
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Sites.Add(newSite);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
                }
                catch (DbUpdateException dbEx)
                {
                    //We have a duplicate key exception on the Address
                    if (dbEx.InnerException.Message.Contains("duplicate key row") &&
                        dbEx.InnerException.Message.Contains("IX_Address_NameOrNumber_PostCode"))
                    {
                        //Address duplicateAddress = _context.Addresses.First(a => a.NameOrNumber.Equals(Address.NameOrNumber) && a.PostCode.Equals(Address.PostCode));
                        //Site.AddressID = duplicateAddress.ID;

                        var errorMessage = "This Name or Number and Post Code combination already exists, please check and try again";
                        ModelState.AddModelError("NameOrNumber", errorMessage);
                        ModelState.AddModelError("PostCode", errorMessage);

                        PopulateRegionsDropDownList(_context, newSite.RegionID);
                        PopulateCountriesDropDownList(_context, newSite.Address.Country);

                        return Page();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Error saving Site details", ex);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(ModelState.ErrorCount);

            PopulateRegionsDropDownList(_context, newSite.RegionID);
            PopulateCountriesDropDownList(_context, newSite.Address.Country);
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

That all seems to work pretty well, and I can happily create a site and it's related address, and set the region no problems. Everything binds nicely, minus the Country, but the ID gets passed in nicely, so I can just set the value and all is good in the world.

Now I try to do the same with the Update, and things don't work so good, I can happily update the `Site` entity, but no such luck with changes to the address.

This is the `Edit.cshtml` page for the `Site` with the partial for the `Address`:

```
@page "{id:int}"
@model MyProject.Areas.Admin.Pages.Sites.EditModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Site";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Site - @Model.Site.Name</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Site.ID" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Site.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Site.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Site.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Site.Region" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Site.RegionID" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.RegionNamesSL">
                    <option value="">-- Select Region --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Site.Region" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input asp-for="Site.AddressID" type="hidden" />
            <partial name="_Address" model="@Model.Site.Address" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Site.MainPhone" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Site.MainPhone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Site.MainPhone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" title="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="mobile-hidden">Save</span> <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Save" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                @*<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />*@
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the `Edit.cshtml.cs` for the corresponding Edit page:

```
    public class EditModel : SelectListsPageModel
    {
        private readonly MyProject.Data.MyProjectContext _context;

        public EditModel(MyProject.Data.MyProjectContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Site Site { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Site = await _context.Sites
                .Include(s => s.Address)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Country)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

            if (Site == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            PopulateRegionsDropDownList(_context, Site.RegionID);
            PopulateCountriesDropDownList(_context, Site.Address.Country); //TODO:  Fix Setting wrong country

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id, int countryID)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                PopulateRegionsDropDownList(_context, Site.RegionID);
                PopulateCountriesDropDownList(_context, Site.Address.Country);

                return Page();
            }

            var siteToUpdate = await _context.Sites
                .Include(s => s.Address)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Country)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

            if (siteToUpdate == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Failed to find Site with ID {id}");
            }

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Site>(
                siteToUpdate,
                "Site",
                s => s.Name,
                s => s.RegionID,
                s => s.MainPhone,
                s => s.Address))
            {

                try
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!SiteExists(Site.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

        private bool SiteExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Sites.Any(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
```

I've tried several iterations of the above, including having an `Address` object which binds the properties, but I can't seem to make it work.

I guess my questions are this:

1. What am I doing wrong and why doesn't the Edit page update the Address?
2. Am I going about this the right way, or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Can you show TryUpdateModelAsync?

Comment: Sorry - that's just a method from PageModel [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel.tryupdatemodelasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_RazorPages_PageModel_TryUpdateModelAsync__1___0_System_String_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ModelBinding_IValueProvider_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Object_____), Is there something specific you want to see? Apologies if i'm missing something.

Comment: Can you set the State of Entity before SaveChanges? like `context.Entry(author).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: I've tried that by passing in `siteToUpdate.Address`, but checking the object it's not actually been bound.  So i've also tried a separate `Address` property on the model, which binds the address back to it, but whenever I try to update the Address (even by setting the state), I get 0 rows affected.

Am I approaching this whole thing correctly, or is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to make this work, i'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it allows you to use the partial view for the Address, and update the Address and the Site object together.

I had to initially make a few changes to the Models, I figured out that the code was getting a little confused by all the `ID`'s being called `ID`, so I updated the various `ID` fields to include entity name:

```
    public class Country
    {
        [Column("ID")]
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        // Other props here
    }

    [Index(nameof(NameOrNumber), nameof(PostCode), IsUnique = true)]
    public class Address
    {
        [Column("ID")]
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        // Other props here
    }

    public class Site
    {
        [Column("ID")]
        public int SiteID { get; set; }
        // Other props here
    }
```

I then included an `Address` property in the PageModel, which I bound, to ensure it got populated with the updated Address data.  After that, all I had to do was write a small mapper method to update the values in the `Site.Address` with the values from the `Address`, and EF took care of the rest.  I actually moved all of this code into my own `PageModel` class which I inherit from as the address will be used in multiple places.

So the final `Edit.cshtml.cs` code looks something like the below:

```
    public class EditModel : RegionWithAddressPageModel
    {
        private readonly MyProject.Data.MyProjectContext _context;

        public EditModel(MyProject.Data.MyProjectContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Site Site { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return NotFound();

            Site = await _context.Sites
                .Include(s => s.Address)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Country)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

            if (Site == null)
                return NotFound();

            PopulateRegionsDropDownList(_context, Site.RegionID);
            PopulateCountriesDropDownList(_context, Site.Address.Country);

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                PopulateRegionsDropDownList(_context, Site.RegionID);
                PopulateCountriesDropDownList(_context, Site.Address.Country);

                return Page();
            }

            var siteToUpdate = await _context.Sites
                    .Include(s => s.Address)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

            if (siteToUpdate == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            MapAddress(siteToUpdate.Address);

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Site>(
                siteToUpdate,
                "Site",
                s => s.Name,
                s => s.RegionID,
                s => s.MainPhone))
            {
                try
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!SiteExists(Site.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

        private bool SiteExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Sites.Any(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
```

And the custom `PageModel` class called `RegionWithAddressPageModel` actually inherits from `AddressPageModel`.  The Region version includes the methods to populate and manage the region drop down where it's required.  So the final code to update the Address is in the `AddressPageModel` class:

```
    public class AddressPageModel : PageModel
    {
        public SelectList CountryNamesSL { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public Address Address { get; set; }

        public void PopulateCountriesDropDownList(TitanContext _context, object selectedCountry = null)
        {
            IOrderedQueryable<Country> countriesQuery = from c in _context.Countries
                                                        orderby c.DisplayOrder ascending, c.Name
                                                        select c;

            if (selectedCountry == null)
                selectedCountry = _context.Countries.OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder).OrderBy(c => c.Name).First();

            CountryNamesSL = new SelectList(countriesQuery.AsNoTracking(),
                                        nameof(Country.CountryID),
                                        nameof(Country.Name),
                                        selectedCountry);

            ViewData["CountryNamesSL"] = CountryNamesSL;
        }

        public void MapAddress(Address destinationObject)
        {
            destinationObject.NameOrNumber = Address.NameOrNumber;
            destinationObject.Street = Address.Street;
            destinationObject.AddressLine2 = Address.AddressLine2;
            destinationObject.AddressLine3 = Address.AddressLine3;
            destinationObject.City = Address.City;
            destinationObject.County = Address.County;
            destinationObject.PostCode = Address.PostCode;
            destinationObject.Country = Address.Country;
            destinationObject.CountryID = Address.CountryID;
        }
    }
```

Hopefully it helps somebody else looking to do something similar.  As I said before, it's probably not the neatest solution, and there may be alternate ways to achieve this, but this has worked quite nicely for me.